# Can Layouts be created in terms of API Level

Tags: android, layout

I wish to use 'switch' in my Project Layout but the min sdk required for it is '14' but I want to run my project run for lower versions too.

Any solution to the above issue ?

The code I have been using

```
<Switch
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/switch_track_holo_dark" />
```

Comment: does it absolutely have to be a 'switch'? Can you accomplish your goal with a Checkbox as well? The advantage of the Checkbox is the backwards compatibility.

Comment: accomplishment is fine but I have the same aPp on iOS with the horizontal toggle so I want my android app to look same thats the reason I'm using switch because android doesnt provides Horizontal toggle.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, you can have two different .xml files one without switch (main) and one with switch (main1).

Then in your onCreate method you will check for API level and setContent for each case.

Example:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    int apiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
    if (apiVersion >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH){
         setContentView(R.layout.main1);
    } else{
         setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

}
```

Comment: This works fine with the lower version but with higher version throws some exception at android.view.ViewGroup.jumpDrawablesToCurrentState(ViewGroup.java:5158)

Comment: Please list ur entire xml file